# Add script tag from an array

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add javascript to the DOM from array below in a loop so that when scripts[0] is loaded then scripts[1] loads and so on.

```
var scripts = [["external", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"],
               ["internal", "$('body').append('hello world');"],
               ["internal", "//some javascript code"],
               ["external", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"]];
```

Below is my current code

```
for ( var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++ ) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
    if ( scripts[i][0] == "external" ) script.src = scripts[i][1];
    if ( scripts[i][0] == "internal" ) script.innerHTML = scripts[i][1];
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: [document-ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) not enough ?

Comment: I don’t see how document.ready helps in this scenario. I know there is an onload event for script element but that doesn’t seem to fire.

Comment: The scripts are not loaded, or they load but with async errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working with the code below.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

```js
var urls = [
 "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
 "$('body').append('hello world');",
 "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js",
 "console.log('hi there');"];

var i = 0;
var recursiveCallback = function() {
  if (i++ < urls.length - 1) {
    loadScript(urls[i], recursiveCallback)
  } else {
    alert('All scripts loaded successfully!');
  }
}
loadScript(urls[0], recursiveCallback);
function loadScript(url, callback) {
 var script = document.createElement("script");
 script.type = "text/javascript";
 if (script.readyState) { // Internet Explorer
  script.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
    script.readyState == "complete") {
    script.onreadystatechange = null;
    callback();
   }
  };
 } else {
  script.onload = function() {
   callback();
  };
 }
 if ( url.substring(0, 4) == "http" ) {
  script.src = url;
 } else {
  script.innerHTML = url;
  callback();
 }
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```